# Set all values of a passed 2D boolean array to false?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, 2d

I have a 2D boolean called 'test' that has contents of both 'true' and 'false', randomly set.

I'm trying to create a method that will set all contents of 'test' to false.

This is my attempt:

```
public static void clearArray( boolean[][] test) {
    Arrays.fill(test[1], false);
}
```

If you're wondering why I have [1] there, the answer is  "I don't know. At least eclipse would let me run it."

Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Thank you as always, stackoverflow.

Comment: Thats because it takes single array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void clearArray( boolean[][] test) {
    for (boolean[] row: test) 
      Arrays.fill(row, false);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're almost correct, just loop over the first level of the array and call `Arrays.fill` on each 2nd level array.

```
public static void clearArray( boolean[][] test) {
  for( boolean[] secondLvl : test ) {
   Arrays.fill( secondLvl , false);
  }
}
```

Note that 2D arrays are basically just an array of arrays, i.e. you get an array of boolean arrays if you have `boolean[][]`. Note that the second level array (i.e. the inner `boolean[]`) would have to be initialized first, i.e. right after creating the 2D array all inner arrays are null.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Logically, this is the correct way:

```
for(int i=0; i<test.length; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<test[i].length; j++) {
        test[i][j] = false;
    }
}
```

Or it can be done the way you want, like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<test.length; i++) {
    Arrays.fill(test[i], false);
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing an `i` :).

Comment: @Thomas if you are referring to the `test[].length`, if it's not a square array and a 2D array with different sub-lengths, then yes. Edited :)

Answer (score 2):

Thats because [Arrays.fill](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(boolean[],%20boolean)) takes single array.

```
public static void clearArray( boolean[][] test) 
{   
  for ( int i=0 ; i < test.rowCount; i++)
     Arrays.fill(test[i], false);     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void clearArray( boolean[][] test) {
    for(boolean[] inTest: test)
        Arrays.fill(inTest, false);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also the `streams` approach:

```
public static void clearArray(boolean[][] b) {
    Arrays.stream(b).forEach(a -> Arrays.fill(a, false));
}

public void test() {
    boolean[][] b = new boolean[4][4];
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        b[i][i] = true;
    }
    System.out.println("Before:" + Arrays.deepToString(b));
    clearArray(b);
    System.out.println("After:" + Arrays.deepToString(b));
}
```